# Django URL pattern does not match with my config

Tags: django-templates

I'm new with Django, I'm having a problem with the url of the page  "`DetailLivre.html`" it shows :

Using the `URLconf` defined in `Ilhem.urls`, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^Bibliotheque/ ^$ [name='index']
^Bibliotheque/ ^(?P<livre_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='DetailLivre']
^admin/
```

The current URL, `Bibliotheque/BOOK1/`, didn't match any of these.*

I'm using: `Python 2.7.6`, `django 1.8.5` can you please help?

**index.html:**

```html
<h1>La liste des Livres </h1>
 
{% block content %}
    {% block theme %}
    {% load bootstrap_themes %}
    {% bootstrap_styles theme='default' type='min.css' %}
    {% bootstrap_styles theme='cosmo' type='css' %}
    {% bootstrap_styles theme='united' type='less' %}
    {% bootstrap_script use_min=True %}
    {% endblock theme %}
{% if BookList%}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <ul>
    {% for livre in BookList %}
        <li><a href="/Bibliotheque/{{ livre.Titre }}/">{{ livre.Titre }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
{% else %}
    <p>Pas de Livres.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**DetailLivre.html**

```html
<h1>{{ Auteur }}</h1>

 <label for="Nom">{{ Auteur.Nom }}</label><br />
 <label for="Prenom">{{ Auteur.Prenom }}</label><br />
 <label for="dateNaissance">{{ Auteur.dateNaissance }}</label><br />
 <label for="Lieu_de_naissance">{{ Auteur.Lieu_de_naissance }}</label><br />
 <label for="Specialite">{{ Auteur.Specialite }}</label>
```

**Views.py**

```js
    
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import Livre, Auteur

def index(request):
    
    BookList = Livre.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('Bibliotheque/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'BookList': BookList,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

def DetailLivre(request, livre_id):
livre = Livre.objects.get(pk=livre_id)
return render(request, 'Bibliotheque/DetailLivre.html', {'livre.Titre': livre.Titre})
```

**url.py**

```js
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<livre_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailLivre, name='DetailLivre'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you have missing BOOK prefix `BOOK(?P<livre_id>[-\d]+)`